# rebuilding dataframe by moving values in rows and columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, visualization

I have a data frame

| idx | bar | Y | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1~3 | 0 | 140 |
| 1 | 1~3 | 1 | 257 |
| 2 | 4~8 | 0 | 33 |
| 3 | 4~8 | 1 | 117 |
| 4 | gt8 | 0 | 13 |
| 5 | gt8 | 1 | 36 |

I want to convert this dataframe into

|  | bar | 0 | 1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1~3 | 140 | 257 |
| 1 | 4~8 | 33 | 117 |
| 2 | gt8 | 13 | 36 |

and then make a stack bar chart from converted dataframe

how can I accomplish this task

Not able to move forward at all.

Comment: You can reformat your data using `df.pivot(columns='Y', values='count', index='bar').reset_index()` but it's unclear what you want the stacked bar chart to look like. Please [edit] your question with details

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi Nick. I wanted a simple stacked bar showing count of Ys (0,1). The solution you provided worked. Thanks V much